# Problem when getting the day name in SQL Server from a number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to get the `dayname` from SQL, with as input only a number representing a day of the week.

When I run this code

```
select  
    datename(dw, '20210115'),
    datepart(dw, '20210115')
```

it returns `Friday`, `6`

So I thought that the number `6` means `Friday`

Then I do the following

```
select datename(dw, 6)
```

but instead of returning `Friday` it returns `Sunday`

So, what is the proper way to get the `dayname` from SQL Server with only a weekday number as input?

Comment: 6 isn't a date. `datename` works with *dates* which means `6` was implicitly converted to a datetime, as if `cast(6 as datetime)` was called. Specifically, it was converted to `1900-01-07`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateName()` and `DatePart()` rely on specific settings (e.g. [`SET DATEFIRST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))

So whilst a value of `6` might represent "Friday" for you right now, the same code might return a different value in a different session for you or for other users.

This is why I don't use those functions, but instead create a calendar table with metadata to inform me of the week day.

The code I use looks like this:

```sql
...
     , CASE WHEN DateDiff(dd, '1900-01-01', the_date) % 7 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As is_monday
     , CASE WHEN DateDiff(dd, '1900-01-01', the_date) % 7 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As is_tuesday
     , CASE WHEN DateDiff(dd, '1900-01-01', the_date) % 7 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As is_wednesday
     , CASE WHEN DateDiff(dd, '1900-01-01', the_date) % 7 = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As is_thursday
     , CASE WHEN DateDiff(dd, '1900-01-01', the_date) % 7 = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As is_friday
     , CASE WHEN DateDiff(dd, '1900-01-01', the_date) % 7 = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As is_saturday
     , CASE WHEN DateDiff(dd, '1900-01-01', the_date) % 7 = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As is_sunday
...
```

This will work on all SQL Server databases, regardless of settings.

If you want this to just return the date name then it could be written as:

```sql
CASE DateDiff(dd, '1900-01-01', the_date) % 7
  WHEN 0 THEN 'Monday'
  WHEN 1 THEN 'Tuesday'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'Wednesday'
  WHEN 3 THEN 'Thursday'
  WHEN 4 THEN 'Friday'
  WHEN 5 THEN 'Saturday'
  WHEN 6 THEN 'Sunday'
END AS day_of_week
```

### How This Approach Works

We calculate the number of days between the input (in these examples `the_date`) and a known, fixed point in time.

The date `1900-01-01` is used because it is the "default" (not the right word, but I can't think of a better one right now!) i.e. what a value of `0` would be cast to.

`1900-01-01` also happens to be a **Monday**!

Every 7th day after that is another Monday, which is what the modulus 7 (`% 7`) bit is responsible for working out!

Comment: Using a calendar table looks like the best solution. thanks